# Auto-stop panorama after one loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using this panorama script: http://jsfiddle.net/zFft4/24/
I now have the animation/scrolling to stop at the end of the first loop.

What I would like is for the animation to stop at the END OF THE IMAGE and not to go all the way to the start position. If I hard-code right limit values I can get it to work somewhat, but because the live version uses a full-width viewport I cannot get it working when I resize the browser window.

Any help much appreciated...

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.panorama = function (options) {
    this.each(function () {
        var settings = {
            viewport_width: 100,
            speed: 20000,
            direction: 'left',
            control_display: 'yes',
            start_position: 0,
            auto_start: true,
            auto_stop: 'true',
            mode_360: true
        };
        if (options) $.extend(settings, options);
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var elemWidth = parseInt($(this).attr('width'));
        var elemHeight = parseInt($(this).attr('height'));
        var currentElement = this;
        var panoramaViewport, panoramaContainer;
        var bMouseMove = false;
        var mouseMoveStart = 0;
        var mouseMoveMarginStart = 0;

        $(this).attr('unselectable', 'on')
            .css('position', 'relative')
            .css('-moz-user-select', 'none')
            .css('-webkit-user-select', 'none')
            .css('margin', '0')
            .css('padding', '0')
            .css('border', 'none')
            .wrap("<div class='panorama-container'></div>");
        if (settings.mode_360) $(this).clone().insertAfter(this);

        panoramaContainer = $(this).parent();
        panoramaContainer.css('height', elemHeight + 'px').css('overflow', 'hidden').wrap("<div class='panorama-viewport'></div>").parent().css('width', settings.viewport_width + '%')
            .append("<div class='panorama-control'><a href='#' class='panorama-control-left'>&nbsp;</a> <a href='#' class='panorama-control-pause'>&nbsp;</a> <a href='#' class='panorama-control-right'>&nbsp;</a> </div>");

        panoramaViewport = panoramaContainer.parent();

        panoramaViewport.mousedown(function (e) {
            if (!bMouseMove) {
                bMouseMove = true;
                mouseMoveStart = e.clientX;
            }
            return false;
        }).mouseup(function () {
            bMouseMove = false;
            mouseMoveStart = 0;
            return false;
        }).mousemove(function (e) {
            if (bMouseMove) {
                var delta = parseInt((mouseMoveStart - e.clientX) / 30);
                if ((delta > 10) || (delta < 10)) {
                    var newMarginLeft = parseInt(panoramaContainer.css('marginLeft')) + (delta);
                    if (settings.mode_360) {
                        if (newMarginLeft > 0) {
                            newMarginLeft = -elemWidth;
                        }
                        if (newMarginLeft < -elemWidth) {
                            newMarginLeft = 0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (newMarginLeft > 0) {
                            newMarginLeft = 0;
                        }
                        if (newMarginLeft < -elemWidth) {
                            newMarginLeft = -elemWidth;
                        }
                    }
                    panoramaContainer.css('marginLeft', newMarginLeft + 'px');
                }

            }
        }).bind('contextmenu', function () {
            return false;
        });

        panoramaViewport.css('height', elemHeight + 'px').css('overflow', 'hidden').find('a.panorama-control-left').bind('click', function () {
            $(panoramaContainer).stop();
            settings.direction = 'right';
            panorama_animate(panoramaContainer, elemWidth, settings);
            return false;
        });
        panoramaViewport.bind('click', function () {
            $(panoramaContainer).stop();
        });
        panoramaViewport.find('a.panorama-control-right').bind('click', function () {
            $(panoramaContainer).stop();
            settings.direction = 'left';
            panorama_animate(panoramaContainer, elemWidth, settings);
            return false;
        });
        panoramaViewport.find('a.panorama-control-pause').bind('click', function () {
            $(panoramaContainer).stop();
            return false;
        });

        if (settings.control_display == 'yes') {
            panoramaViewport.find('.panorama-control').show();
        } else if (settings.control_display == 'auto') {
            panoramaViewport.bind('mouseover', function () {
                $(this).find('.panorama-control').show();
                return false;
            }).bind('mouseout', function () {
                $(this).find('.panorama-control').hide();
                return false;
            });

        }

        $(this).parent().css('margin-left', '-' + settings.start_position + 'px');

        if (settings.auto_start) panorama_animate(panoramaContainer, elemWidth, settings);

    });

    function panorama_animate(element, elemWidth, settings) {
        currentPosition = 0 - parseInt($(element).css('margin-left'));

        if (settings.direction == 'right') {

            $(element).animate({
                marginLeft: 0
            }, ((settings.speed / elemWidth) * (currentPosition)), 'linear', function () {
                if (settings.mode_360) {
                    $(element).css('marginLeft', '-' + (parseInt(parseInt(elemWidth)) + 'px'));
        if (settings.auto_stop != 'true') {
            panorama_animate(element, elemWidth, settings);
        }
                }
            });
        } else {

            var rightlimit;
            if (settings.mode_360) rightlimit = elemWidth;
            else rightlimit = elemWidth - settings.viewport_width;

            $(element).animate({
                marginLeft: -rightlimit
            }, ((settings.speed / rightlimit) * (rightlimit - currentPosition)), 'linear', function () {
                if (settings.mode_360) {
                    $(element).css('margin-left', 0);
        if (settings.auto_stop != 'true') {
            panorama_animate(element, elemWidth, settings);
        }
                }
            });
        }


    }

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img.panorama").panorama();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Still looking for a solution to this...anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This block of code:

```
if (settings.mode_360) {
    $(element).css('margin-left', 0);
    panorama_animate(element, elemWidth, settings);
}
```

Basically says - go one round and then start over again (it calls `panorama_animate()` again).
So you need to remove the line (or comment it out):

```
if (settings.mode_360) {
    $(element).css('margin-left', 0);
    //panorama_animate(element, elemWidth, settings);
}
```

And it should do what you need. Notice that this code block exists **twice** in the code (lines 124 and 138).

Comment: Thanks Ofir - that worked great! The client is now asking if it's possible to end the animation at the end of the image rather than ending the loop at the beginning. Is that even possible?

Comment: Change `mode_360:` to `false`? Is that what you wanted? (Also, if you liked the answer up-vote it :))

Comment: Almost, but if mode_360 is off, it scrolls past the image and leaves a gray background which is not desired. The client wants the 360 look but only wants the image to scroll to the end and not past

Comment: Still looking for a solution to this...anyone have any ideas?